# How execute container in Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: flask, containers, google-compute-engine, gunicorn

I have a Flask application deployed in a container inside a Google Cloud Compute Instance, listening on port 5000 with gunicorn.

bootstrap.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app
```

I have created the appropriate Firewall rule to open that port, and tagged my instance with that rule.

```
NAME                    NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW      DENY  DISABLED
rule-allow-tcp-5000     default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:5000        False
```

The command `netstat -a` inside the instance, shows the port listening:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        6      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

But when I try to access my instance externally through a REST client, it keeps waiting infinitely for a response.

Even internally, from the SSH of the instance, I don't have a response:

```
nahuel@instance-1 ~ $ wget localhost:5000
--2019-08-20 12:27:05--  http://localhost:5000/
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:5000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

I think that the problem has to do with the container, here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-buster
RUN useradd -m tagger
WORKDIR /home/tagger

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt && pip install gunicorn

COPY autokeras autokeras
COPY static static
COPY tagger tagger
COPY templates templates
COPY model model
COPY application.cfg config.ini tagger-xxxxxx.json main.py wsgi.py bootstrap.sh ./
RUN mkdir uploads
RUN chmod +x bootstrap.sh

ENV FLASK_APP main.py
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS tagger-xxxxxx.json
RUN chown -R tagger:tagger ./
USER tagger

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["./bootstrap.sh"]
```

When I test my container locally, running the container with the -p option, it works OK, but I don't know how to make the Compute Instance to open my container port.

Thank you for your help.

---

I have reduced the problem as to the container inside the Google Instance VM, as I can see in the container logs that gunicorn is working, but it doesn't process my requests.

Comment: https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/administration/use-firewall/ . that is neither  Docker question nor python ...

Comment: I have created the appropriate Firewall rule to open that port, and tagged my instance with that rule, but I still can't access my container port. Even inside the VM instance, I can't access the port 5000 of my container. If I build and deploy locally, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check the follow:

- When you run your Docker container from the image you create from your dockerfile, expose the 5000 port on both your host machine and the container, Publish or expose port (-p, --expose) on this [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

`docker run -p 5000:5000`

- Get a terminal session to your container, check from there if the service it's running and it's listening on the proper port (5000)

`docker exec -t -i container /bin/bash`

- When you run `wget localhost:5000` the connection go to your host machine not to your container, if the port forwarding are no set properly the connection never reach the container. You can retrieve the local ip assigned to your container in order to test connectivity on the specific port (use the wget)

  `docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container`

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't solve my problem. I have reduced the problem as to the container inside the Google Instance VM, as I can see the logs that gunicorn is working, but it doesn't process my requests.